# Why does Openbsd doesn't keep my inet6 routes?

Tags: ipv6, bsd, openbsd

I have a router.
This router has two interfaces - one into my LAN with a static IP (xl1 with fd01::1/64) and one with a dynamic IP ( xl0 with autoconf ).
My desktop has fd01::2/64. If I ping from fd01::2 to fd01::1 it works just fine.

net.inet6.ip6.forwarding is activated.

If I do "ifconfig xl0 inet6 autoconf" the ping suddenly stops.

The following route -n show output on the first situation (no autoconf on xl0)

```
fd01::/64 link#3  UC  1 0  -  4 xl1  
fd01::1  00:50:04:12:34:56 UHLl   0 0 -  1 lo0  
fd01::2  b8:ac:6f:12:34:56 UHLc   0 3 -  4 xl1
```

After this i do "ifconfig xl0 inet6 autoconf"

```
fd01::1 00:50:04:2a:3d:bf UHLl 0 0 - 1 lo0  
fd23:b4dc:4b1e::/64 link#1 UC 0 0  - 4 xl0  
fd23:b4dc:4b1e:0:210:5aff:fe12:345 00:10:5a:31:23:45  UHLl 0 0 - 1 lo0  
fd23:b4dc:4b1e:0:34b6:509e:6d80:af07 00:10:5a:31:23:45 UHLl 0 0 - 1 lo0
```

The route for fd01::/64 completely disappeared.

My question is: Is this normal behavior or is this maybe a bug in OpenBSD 5.7 ?

Answer (score 1):

The `fd00::/8` range has some rules about assigning the various parts of the address.  The next 40 bits are known as the Global ID, and, according to the RFC, they "*MUST be generated with a pseudo-random algorithm*."

Apparently, your OS is attempting to follow the RFC when using auto configuration.  See [RFC 4193, Unique Local IPv6 Unicast Addresses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4193) for details on using the Unique Local address range.

Comment: So there is no way to assign v6 addresses by hand?

Comment: There certainly are are, but special address ranges have special rules. Any global address range allows you to assign addresses as you see fit: manually, DHCPv6, SLAAC, etc.

Comment: How does the router detect "not random generated" Global IDs?
I tried to use 2001:db8::/64 but have the same effect - the routes kicked out. If the fd23 interface went down or the fd23 adresses from xl0 are removed the routes for 2001:db8:: appear.

Comment: I would imagine that auto-configuration tells it to generate a random Global ID. Certainly `01::` doesn't appear to be random. This is something you should discuss with the router manufacturer.